# Script Timeout: exhausted allowed execution time (ROBLOX)

Tags: lua, roblox

I am currently making a game for ROBLOX as a passion project, and I have ran into a problem.

I am making a script so that when the player runs, the FOV of the camera will shoot up, acting like your really fast.

I have successfully  made the code, however when ran in studio or the client, it freezes the game and puts a "Script Timeout: exhausted allowed execution time" in the output.

Is there any way to fix this? Thank you so much!

Code here:

```
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Humanoid = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local Camera = workspace.CurrentCamera
local FovRun = TweenService:Create(workspace.CurrentCamera, TweenInfo.new(0.5), {FieldOfView = 75})
local FovWalk = TweenService:Create(workspace.CurrentCamera, TweenInfo.new(0.5), {FieldOfView = 70})
local Running = false

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(Key, IsTyping)
    if Key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift and not IsTyping then
        if (Humanoid.MoveDirection:Dot(Humanoid.Parent:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart").CFrame.LookVector) > 0) then
            if Running then
                FovWalk:Play()
                Running = false
                Humanoid.WalkSpeed = Humanoid.WalkSpeed - 8
            end
            Running = true
            Humanoid.WalkSpeed = Humanoid.WalkSpeed + 8
            FovRun:Play()
            elseif Humanoid.Health > Humanoid.MaxHealth / 1.5 then
                repeat
                until not Running
            if Humanoid.Health < Humanoid.MaxHealth / 1.5 then
                repeat
                until not Running
            end
        else
            if Running then
                FovWalk:Play()
                Running = false
                Humanoid.WalkSpeed = Humanoid.WalkSpeed - 8
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
repeat
until not Running
```

This is an infinite loop. If you enter it and `Running` is `true` your code will run it forever as `Running` is not being updated in the loop's body.

Roblox will realize that your code is stuck and throw that error message.

Comment: If this line of code is removed, the freezing in the game will stop, however the code will no longer work at all. Tricky code.

Comment: I don't know what that is supposed to mean. this is the answer to your question. if you have a new problem, post a new question with your current code and debugging details. what do you expect to happen, what happens instead...

Comment: Found the solution, actually! Just decided to add a wait() somewhere in the code to fix the whole thing. Marking this as the solution.